# Can driver.installApp() launch another app that is not defined as part of Capabilities Object?

Tags: android, automation, appium

I am using Appium to perform mobile automation. I am facing an issue working with driver.installApp() method of Appium. It gives me the following error -

Unable to install [apps/App2.apk] to device with id [null][Error: Command failed: can't find 'apps/App2.apk' to install]

What I am trying to do is, in capabilities I am setting the details of App1 and launching it. Later I am trying to install App2 with the same driver and facing this issue. I tried referring similar issues but did not find any answer to the issue. I am not quite sure if this usecase of launching App1 via capabilities and installing App2 with the same driver is supported by the API.

Comment: Your App2.apk is in the relative path "apps/App2.apk" ?

Comment: Most importantly why is it showing - to device with id [null] , is your device properly connected

Answer (score 0):

You have give package name there instead of app path.

Ex: `driver.installApp("com.demo.test");`